# SSRS how to count with multiple conditions?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2012, reporting-services-2012

I'm new to expressions in SSRS, hope you can help!

I need to create the following:

"Count [issueID] where [closed] is not null and [due_date] is in the past."

I can do the first bit, but don't know the syntax to add the "...and [due_date] is in the past" in the textbox expression.

Cheers

Lins

Comment: You could probably use `< NOW()` ?

Comment: straight SQL would be:  `SELECT COUNT(issueID) WHERE [closed] IS NOT NULL AND [due_date] < GETDATE()` is but I'm guessing SSRS doesn't know what `GETDATE()` so that might be `NOW()` or `NOW` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to modify your dataset source to return this flag in your data. If you are not going to modify your data then I guess you could...

1. Add a Calculated Field to your Data Set MyCalc.
2. Set the expression for the Calculated Field

   =IIF(!IsNothing(Fields!Closed.Value) && Fields!DueDate.Value < DateTime.Now,1,0)
3. Now you can add an expression similar to

   =IIF(SUM(Fields!MyCal.Value) > 10 , "+10","not + 10")

Comment: Brilliant, yes I can alter the base stored procedure to create a flag for this. Thank you for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select 
count(case when [closed] is not null then [issueID] else 0 end) as 'TotalCount'
from [Your_Table]
where [due_date] <= getdate()
```